# Что за магия с layout?

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-layout

Есть layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Текст"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2000dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Тестирую на эмуляторе Genymotion. На Nexus 7 4.4.4 800x1200 текст не отображается. На всех других устройствах все гуд. Почему так?

**UPD**

Обновил layout. Также заметно, если view2 указать android:layout_height="match_parent", текст отображается, но занимает по высоте не все пространство родительского layout, а только сколько ему нужно.

**UPD2**

Обновил layout. Высота view1 заранее не известна.

Comment: При таких изменениях все упирается в размер view2("wrap_content") если его задать явно, то текст будет виден. Скорее всего, если view2 будет не пустым, то текст тоже отобразится даже с атрибутом "wrap_content".

Comment: @AntonShamanov Да, если указать view2 высоту = match_parent, текст отображается, но занимает вместе с view2 не всю высоту родителя. Указать явно не выйдет, неизвестно заранее сколько будет занимать изображение по высоте.

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит попробовать следующее:
1) Положить RelativeLayout в LinearLayout и поменять в RelativeLayout android:layout_height:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
       ..........

   </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

2) Изменить у ScrollView:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

3) Убрать строчку из Linearlayout android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view1"

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        -----android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view1"------
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">
```

Comment: Если убрать android:layout_alignBottom, layout не будет знать своих границ. и тогда занимает только размер по тексту на всех девайсах

Comment: Да, вот именно, вы хотите что бы весь текст было видно, но при этом не даете ему больше места для размещения. Меня это вгоняет в ступор.

Comment: Как это не даю? Я знаю что изображение будет большое, вот и отдаю тексту от него по высоте все пространство а по горизонтали половину.

Comment: на всех девайвайсах кроме указанного все ок

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить цвет текста.  На красный, например.
Проблема, возможно, в том, что на этом устройстве системный цвет фона белый.

Comment: цвет текста стоит черный, красный думаю не лучше

Answer (score 0):

Если высоту LinearLayout поставить равной view (150dp) текст начинает отображаться.

Немного переделанный код:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Текст"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Высоту в 150dp я указал для наглядности, думал будет проще понять. На самом деле мы не знаем заранее, сколько по высоте будет занимать картинка. То есть значение у view1 , layout_height="wrapContent"

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что проблема из UPD1 решается изменением

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

у RelativeLayout
на

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: Не знаю чем это должно помочь, но я все равно попробовал, не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_height="match_parent" у ScrollView

Comment: Не угадали, не работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй у **TextView** `layout_height: wrap_content`. Мне кажется он у тебя схлопнулся по высоте. Вот и не видно его.

Comment: Да так можно сделать и поместить его в дополнительный layout, для центрирования по вертикали, но parent_layout все равно не занимает все пространство по вертикали, а только сколько занимает TextView.

Comment: Потому что у родительского View **layout_height="wrap_content"** поменяй на **match_parent**

Comment: у parent_layout стоит как вы видите match_parent, и дополнительно созданному так же ставил match_parent.